# From QueryString to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

How can I transform a QueryString like `var1=5&var2=stackoverflow&var3=blah` to a JSON object like:

```
{
    "var1": "5",
    "var2": "stackoverflow",
    "var3": "blah"
}
```

I'm following [this](http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/turning-the-querystring-into-a-json-object-using-javascript/), but it looks like I'm missing out something... I can also use jQuery if needed.

Comment: How exactly does the tutorial code not seem to be working for you?

Comment: Looks like it's returning an array with the object inside, but I need the object only

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Was my suggestion able to help you at all?

Comment: @scniro check my answer...

Comment: @Napolux your answer doesn't explain a whole lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved by doing a manual parsing of the object itself...

```
AjaxForm.prototype.getData = function() {
    var data    = this.$element.serializeArray();
    var object  = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        object[data[i].name] = data[i].value;
    }

    return JSON.stringify(object);
};
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that shows this working? I don't understand what you are doing here - how are you parsing a query string?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure at which point you are struggling with in the mentioned tutorial since you did not provide your snippet, but checking that article out, I was able to craft a fully working example for you (with some improvement suggestions in the comments). Observe the following...

```
function QueryStringToJSON(str) {
    var pairs = str.split('&');
    var result = {};
    pairs.forEach(function (pair) {
        pair = pair.split('=');
        var name = pair[0]
        var value = pair[1]
        if (name.length)
            if (result[name] !== undefined) {
                if (!result[name].push) {
                    result[name] = [result[name]];
                }
                result[name].push(value || '');
            } else {
                result[name] = value || '';
            }
    });
    return (result);
}

var string = 'var1=5&var2=stackoverflow&var3=blah';
var obj = QueryStringToJSON(string);

console.log(obj) // {var1: "5", var2: "stackoverflow", var3: "blah"}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dm1ufzz3/) - working demo

---

Searching around on the web will point you to [jQuery BBQ: `$.deparam`](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/) as an approach to this at some point. This is great, and probably a bit more robust, but you should be able to get away with the above code first, especially if you desire a vanilla solution (which you always should!!)

Comment: You could modify the last line as `return (JSON.stringify(result));` This will give the perfect JSON string. Right now its returning an Object will doesn't print in console.log().

Answer (score 2):

It could be written in one-liner.

```
Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams('var1=5&var2=stackoverflow&var3=blah'))
```

**Runnable snippet:**

```js
const paramsString = "var1=5&var2=stackoverflow&var3=blah";
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

// Iterate the search parameters.
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}

console.log(Object.fromEntries(searchParams));
```

Comment: BEST solution here, not sure why its not upvoted more?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/):

```
$(function(){

  // Values are not coerced.
  var params = $.deparam.querystring();

  debug.log( 'not coerced', params );
  $('#deparam_string').text( JSON.stringify( params, null, 2 ) );

  // Values are coerced.
  params = $.deparam.querystring( true );

  debug.log( 'coerced', params );
  $('#deparam_coerced').text( JSON.stringify( params, null, 2 ) );

  // Highlight the current sample query string link
  var qs = $.param.querystring();

  $('li a').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).attr( 'href' ) === '?' + qs ) {
      $(this).addClass( 'current' );
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
var query="var1=5&var2=stackoverflow&var3=blah";
var arr=query.split("&");
result={};
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    k = arr[i].split('=');
    result[k[0]] = (k[1] || '');
}; 
console.log(result);
```

So here what i am doing
1)split query using "&". you will get array as ["var1=5",....];

2)Again splitting every element of array over "=".

3)taking key as arr[0] and value as arr[1] and if no value then ''.

Note:this is for decodeed URI. If URI is encoded first decode it using decodeURIComponent() function.